# Force *.ts to import over *.tsx

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have two files for my component:

- `app/components/SomeButton.ts`
- `app/components/SomeButton.tsx`

The `.ts` contains most of the logic/code and the `.tsx` extends the `.ts` and contains just the render function.

When I want to import the `.tsx` in some other file (e.g. `App.tsx`) like this:

```
import SomeButton from 'app/components/SomeButton';
```

it tries to import the `.ts` file instead.

Is there a way to force it to load the `.tsx` file instead?

A workaround would be to use 2 different names but having te same name would be a bit cleaner.

Comment: _Why_ do you have that?

Comment: but why do you want to implement it in this way?

Comment: Since I'm using React this will give a nice speration of code and template

Comment: Your choices are to change one or other filename or specify the `.ts` extension explicitly.

Comment: Or you add a dot separated name after the file name which is common when you have situations where you want a number of files related to the same thing. Eg:

`app/components/SomeButton.tsx` `app/components/SomeButton.logic.ts` `app/components/SomeButton.stories.tsx`

Whatever your want to call it.

Comment: If `SomeButton.ts` contains the logic, it's name should start with lowercase letter. Instead use `someButton.ts`.

Comment: @DomA I already thought of just using a different file name, but using the . notation in the file name is an even more elegant solution. I had not thought of this before so thanks for that!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the comment of @DomA I now ended up with this pretty satisfactory construction (though not a perfect answer to the question):

app/components/SomeButton.ts:

```
import React from 'react';

export abstract class SomeButton extends React.Component<{},{}> {

    protected label:string;

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.label = 'Some Button';
    }

    public componentDidMount():void {
        tr('Some Button mounted');
    }

    // ... more code and handlers here..

}
```

app/components/SomeButton.r.tsx: (the `r` is arbitrary)

```
import { SomeButton as Component } from './SomeButton';

export default class SomeButton extends Component {

    public render() {
        return (
            <>
                <button>{this.label}</button>
            </>
        );
    }
}
```

You can now import the component wherever you like like this:
import SomeButton from 'app/components/SomeButton.r';

```
import SomeButton from 'app/components/SomeButton.r';
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply add the desired extension to your import:

```js
import SomeButton from 'app/components/SomeButton.tsx';
```

Although, if I were to split a component into multiple files, I would probably create a folder for that component and keep all the files in there. You could have:

```
└── components
    └── SomeButton
        ├── SomeButton.ts
        ├── SomeButton.tsx
        └── SomeButton.css
```

That way, you're original objective could be accomplished by adding an `index.js` that exports the tsx component as default:

```js
import SomeButton from './SomeButton.tsx';

export default SomeButton;
```

```js
//Your original line of code would now import 'SomeButton.tsx':
import SomeButton from 'app/components/SomeButton';
```

Comment: Problem is that you can't add the extension to the import. That would throw an error:
` An import path cannot end with a '.tsx' extension. Consider importing 'SomeButton.js' instead.`